# Flutter: How to fix ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs

Tags: ios, flutter, uiwebview

When submitting my latest build, Apple suddenly returned a message saying that there was an issue, specifically:

> ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs . See https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiwebview for more information.

Since I'm not using the webview plugin I'm at a loss as to where the `UIWebView API` is being used. Any advice on how to solve this?

This error appears with the latest stable flutter build 1.7.8+hotfix.4 and with the following packages included:

```
http: ^0.12.0
shared_preferences: ^0.4.3
intl: any
permission_handler: ^2.1.2
contacts_service: ^0.2.8
image: ^2.0.5
cached_network_image: ^1.0.0
url_launcher: ^5.0.1
path_provider: ^0.5.0+1
after_layout: ^1.0.7
connectivity: ^0.4.3+1
device_info: ^0.4.0+2
firebase_auth: ^0.11.1+7
firebase_messaging: ^5.1.2
firebase_analytics: ^5.0.0
notification_permissions: ^0.4.0
```

All of the packages have been updated to their latest version.

The output of `flutter doctor` is:

```
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, v1.7.8+hotfix.4, on Mac OS X 10.14.6 18G87, locale en-US)
    • Flutter version 1.7.8+hotfix.4 at /Users/per/flutter
    • Framework revision 20e59316b8 (6 weeks ago), 2019-07-18 20:04:33 -0700
    • Engine revision fee001c93f
    • Dart version 2.4.0

[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
    • Android SDK at /Users/per/Library/Android/sdk
    • Android NDK location not configured (optional; useful for native profiling support)
    • Platform android-28, build-tools 28.0.3
    • Java binary at: /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents/jre/jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)
    • All Android licenses accepted.

[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 10.3)
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 10.3, Build version 10G8
    • CocoaPods version 1.7.4

[✓] iOS tools - develop for iOS devices
    • ios-deploy 1.9.4

[✓] Android Studio (version 3.2)
    • Android Studio at /Applications/Android Studio.app/Contents
    • Flutter plugin version 31.3.1
    • Dart plugin version 181.5656
    • Java version OpenJDK Runtime Environment (build 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b06)

[✓] VS Code (version 1.31.1)
    • VS Code at /Applications/Visual Studio Code.app/Contents
    • Flutter extension version 2.25.1

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • Nexus 6P • 5VT7N15C31001152 • android-arm64 • Android 8.1.0 (API 27)

• No issues found!
```

Comment: You can check if there is open issue for this in github flutter issues. If not please open a issue there.

Comment: The issue is being tracked in the Flutter repo. Lookes like it could be the firebase packages. https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/39470

Comment: I'm getting this as well

Answer (score 25, accepted):

I think it was being used from the firebase_auth plugin.
Try to update it to its latest version and then remember run **pod update**.

Comment: I tend to agree to that as searching through the packets that is the only one having references of UIWebView in it. I have updated to the latest version of firebase_auth now and can't find any references anymore to UIWebView.

Comment: Flutter team seems to be aware. https://github.com/firebase/firebase-ios-sdk/pull/3723

Comment: After updating to firebase_auth 0.14.0+5 and updating the pods, the references to UIWebView seem to be gone. Hopefully that means submission will no go smoothly again.

Answer (score 8):

I have this with our Cordova app and fixed it by updating a dependency.

Are you by any chance using the dependency or an other dependency is using the dependency "cordova-plugin-inappbrowser".

If so, this should be fixed in 3.1.0. See the release notes https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/blob/master/RELEASENOTES.md
And the PR fixing it https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-inappbrowser/pull/271

Update: it's not fixed yet. See issue on cordova-ios: https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/661
Note the: There is no deadline, I've contacted an Apple developer that has been tweeting about moving to WKWebView to see if he can provide more information, will update if I get a response.

Update: Cordova-ios 5.1.0 seems to fix this. See https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/715

Comment: Hm, I am getting the same email even when I remove ALL plugins from my Cordova app.

Comment: Yes, I can confirm I'm also still getting them. So it must also be something else in Cordova. Ionic webview also has this issue: https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/428

Comment: Thanks for the info. I'm not using Cordova, so that cannot be the cause, but the firebase package seems to be causing this.

Comment: @Klaasvaak Did you ever hear anything from the Apple dev?

Comment: @matthewpavkov we were able to release with the warning

Comment: From 22 Nov in version Cordova-ios 5.1.0 these seems to be fixed `GH-715 feat: add optional compile-time decision for disabling UIWebView` https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/pull/715

Comment: The cordova-ios 5.1.0 solution involving the optional flag [is a workaround](https://github.com/apache/cordova-ios/issues/661#issuecomment-594079481) and a real fix will arrive in next major release.

Answer (score 6):

Since this has become the "goto answer" on Google for this rejection message, I'll add a React Native fix.

On React Native, considering that you've been a good developer and are not using UIWebView in your own code, use the following command to find out which of your dependencies still does use UIWebView:

```
grep -r UIWebView node_modules/*
```

There is a bit more info [here](https://www.devsbedevin.net/react-native-itms-90809-warning-from-apple/).

Comment: is there a similar command I could run for the packages in pubspec.yaml?

Comment: @flutter grep -r UIWebView ios/Pods/

Comment: i have this response....grep -r UIWebView ios/Pods/ 
Binary file ios/Pods//TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/TwitterKit matches
ios/Pods//TwitterKit/iOS/TwitterKit.framework/Headers/TWTRTweet.h: *  Suitable for loading in a `UIWebView`, `WKWebView` or passing to Safari:   how to fix

Comment: @DanieleAngelini: looks like a comment in the file. You may ignore

Comment: ok but when i upload in apple store recive warning... ITMS-90809: Deprecated API Usage - Apple will stop accepting submissions of apps that use UIWebView APIs
there is a way to fix? seems i need to force to use safari...

Comment: @DanieleAngelini - then there might me more culprits

Comment: thanks! this helped me find hte culprits. in my case it was react-native-device-info and /react-native-fbsdk.

Answer (score 1):

In my case the problem was the version of the Facebook plugin for Flutter that I was using in debug

I had to change the version from:

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^2.0.1
```

to:

```
flutter_facebook_login: ^3.0.0
```

Also had to change the pod file from:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 4.39.1'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 4.39.1'
```

to:

```
pod 'FBSDKCoreKit', '~> 5.5'
pod 'FBSDKLoginKit', '~> 5.5'
```

Then another problem became with the call of this function

```
fbLogin.logInWithReadPermissions(['email']);
```

just replaced with

```
fbLogin.logIn(['email']);
```

then rebuild everything, and upload again.

Answer (score -1):

Even though I'm not using firebase_auth in my app, I was finding references to UIWEBVIEW in Xcode search from FirebaseAuth. It seems that Pods includes this by default. So this worked for me:

1. Open project in Xcode
2. Open the Pods folder and you will probably see a lot of sub-folders (packages)
3. Right-click on the FirebaseAuth folder and select Delete
4. Then select "Remove References" not "Move to Trash"
5. Build the project
6. The UIWEBVIEW references should be gone

Comment: Difference between `"Remove References" not "Move to Trash"`? can you explain please

Comment: I'm sorry but I don't know the difference.  I got errors when I deleted the folder,but everything worked when I just removed the references.

Comment: "Remove References" will remove the reference of the folder from the Xcode but the folder will still exist on the disk. The folder can be added in Xcode again.

"Move to Trash" will remove the references of the folder from Xcode and also deletes the file from the disk. The folder can not be added in Xcode again.