# How can I create a JavaScript condition to display either image preview of a video or image preview of a picture?

Tags: javascript, html, file-upload, preview

On image preview, when I select a video, an empty image box is displayed on the right side of the video image preview.  And when I select a picture, an empty space is displayed on the left side of the picture image preview.  So both `<video>` tag and `<img>` tag are displayed together.

Here is the code of the relevant  **HTML**  part, which is inside a form tag:

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="input-group-prepend" for="image_name">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach a photo or video"></i> 
    <video class="image_Preview"></video>
    <img class="image_Preview">
  </label>
  <input id="image_name" name="image_name" class="file" type="file" data-count="0" style="display: none;">

</form>
```

Here is the relevant  **jQuery**  part:

```
$(document).on('click change', '.file, .submit', function() {

if ($(this).is('.file')) {
     $(this).closest('.input-group').find('.image_Preview').attr('src', window.URL.createObjectURL(this.files[0]))
      .css({"width":"250px","height":"150px"});
```

I want either `<video>` tag or `<img>` tag to be displayed, but not both.

Here I created the following code.  First, I take the file extension from input tag to see whether it is jpg or mp4. If the file extension is jpg it goes to `if` condition, and if it is mp4 it goes to `else` condition.  The problem is that I cannot make `var ext` global.  It is local no matter how much I try to make it global.

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="input-group-prepend" for="image_name">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach a photo or video"></i> 

<script>
  function getFile(filePath) {
    return filePath.substr(filePath.lastIndexOf('\\') + 1).split('.')[0];    
}

var ext;

function getoutput() {
  outputfile.value = getFile(image_name.value);
  ext = extension.value = image_name.value.split('.')[1];
  console.log(ext);
}

getoutput();
console.log(ext);   

if (ext == 'jpg') {
  document.write('<img class="image_Preview">');
  document.write('<h1>It worked for jpg!</h1>');

} else if (ext == 'mp4') {
  document.write('<video class="image_Preview"></video>');
  document.write('<h1>It worked for mp4!</h1>');
}
</script>

  </label>
  <input id="image_name" name="image_name" class="file" type="file" data-count="0" style="display: none;"  onChange='getoutput()'> <br>
      Output Filename <input id='outputfile' type='text' name='outputfile'><br>
      Extension <input id='extension' type='text' name='extension'>

</form>
```

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp

Comment: where is the javascript code ?

Comment: I did look at w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_if.asp, but I couldn't make it work in my own program.

Comment: How are you selecting between img and video like a radio button etc

Comment: No, when I click the image preview icon, there is a choice between uploading a picture or a video.  Just similar to FaceBook.   The problem is when I select either video or picture, the  other tag is displayed along side of it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give the img and video different classes, and hide and show image/video based on the file type/extension.

```
<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="input-group-prepend" for="image_name">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach a photo or video"></i> 
  </label>
  <input id="image_name" name="image_name" class="file" type="file" data-count="0" style="display: none;">

</form>

<video style="display: none;" class="video_Preview" controls></video>
<img style="display: none;" class="image_Preview">
```

Jquery

```
$('#image_name').on('change', function(event) {

  if (
    !event ||
    !event.target ||
    !event.target.files ||
    event.target.files.length === 0
  ) {
    return;
  }

  const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  const imgExtensions = ['jpg', 'png'];
  const videoExtensions = ['mkv', 'mp4', 'webm'];
  const name = event.target.files[0].name;
  const lastDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');

  const ext = name.substring(lastDot + 1);

  if (imgExtensions.includes(ext)) {
    $(".video_Preview").hide(); // hide video preview
    $(".image_Preview").show().attr("src", fileUrl);
  } else if (videoExtensions.includes(ext)) {
    $(".image_Preview").hide(); // hide image preview
    $(".video_Preview").show().attr("src", fileUrl);
  }
});
```

```js
$('#image_name').on('change', function(event) {
  if (
    !event ||
    !event.target ||
    !event.target.files ||
    event.target.files.length === 0
  ) {
    return;
  }

  const fileUrl = window.URL.createObjectURL(event.target.files[0]);
  const imgExtensions = ['jpg', 'png'];
  const videoExtensions = ['mkv', 'mp4', 'webm'];
  const name = event.target.files[0].name;
  const lastDot = name.lastIndexOf('.');

  const ext = name.substring(lastDot + 1);

  if (imgExtensions.includes(ext)) {
    $(".video_Preview").hide();  // hide video preview
    $(".image_Preview").show().attr("src", fileUrl);
  } else if (videoExtensions.includes(ext)) {
    $(".image_Preview").hide(); // hide image preview
    $(".video_Preview").show().attr("src", fileUrl);
  }
});
```

```html
<link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form  method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">

  <label class="input-group-prepend" for="image_name">
    <i class="fa fa-camera" data-toggle="tooltip" title="Attach a photo or video"></i> 
  </label>
  <input id="image_name" name="image_name" class="file" type="file" data-count="0" style="display: none;">

</form>

<video style="display: none;" class="video_Preview" controls></video>
<img style="display: none;" class="image_Preview">
```