# How do I access this response from the console.log?

Tags: reactjs, react-native, console.log

Usually, it is easier for me to do this with `fetch`, but this package does not use `fetch`. 
I read other questions similar to mine and here is my attempt in trying to do it:

```
SelectPhoto = () =>{
ImagePicker.openPicker({
}).then((imgResponse) => {
  console.log(imgResponse.path); <-- Trying to access the path
});
}
```

I keep getting `undefined` and here are my console log results:

```
0:{size: 745660, mime: "image/jpeg", height: 2960, width: 1440, path: "file:///storage/emulated/0/DCIM/Screenshots/Screenshot_20180617-173313.jpg"} length:1
```

Can anyone help me out with this? Thank you so much!

Comment: though I don't know for sure: 1.) use ```imgResponse[0].path```? or 2.) is path protected from being read in the first place?

Comment: Ok this worked. Also, I don't think so because it tells me I can do it from this package: https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-native-customized-image-picker. Now all I need to do is figure out how to change the state to that path. @SebastianRothbucher

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using [react-native-customized-image-picker](https://github.com/mg365/react-native-customized-image-picker).

According to their [docs](https://github.com/mg365/react-native-customized-image-picker#select-from-gallery) and your console.log output, you can get the path and set it to the state as follows:

```
import React from 'react'
import ImagePicker from 'react-native-customized-image-picker'

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor (props) {
    super(props)

    this.state = { path: null }
    this.handleClick = this.handleClick.bind(this)
  }

  handleClick () {
    ImagePicker.openPicker({}).then(image => {
      const path = image[0].path

      this.setState({ path })
    })
  }

  render () {
    return <div onClick={this.handleClick}>Select image</div>
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!

Comment: One more thing, how would I get just the filename with this package?

Comment: If the library doesn't return the `filename` in the `image` object, then you can manually get it as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/423385/4312466