# How to print the filename of a file that i put in an <input type="file"> in an <input type="text">?

Tags: javascript, html, forms

```js
$('input[type="file"]').change(function(){
        $('input[type="text"]').val( $(this).val() );
});
```

```html
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlFile1">File</label>
      <input type="file" name="documento" class="form-control-file" required>
</div>
<div class="form-group">
      <label for="exampleFormControlInput1">Name File</label>
      <input type="text" name="dpro_filename_scan" class="form-control" required>
</div>
```

I have this js file but it print C:\fakepath\filename. I need only the filename.

Comment: Duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/423376/1531971

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)