# How to get only filename in chokidar rather than full path

Tags: javascript, node.js

i wanted to get only `filename` being `changed,removed,rename`   but i'm getting full file path

**Question:** i wanted to get full `filename` being changed rather path or doing string on full path

**here is what i'm trying:**

```
  var fileLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'folder/');

    var watcher = chokidar.watch(fileLocation, {
        persistent: true
      });

      watcher
      .on('add', path => {console.log(`File ${path} has been added name:`); })
      .on('change', path => {console.log(`File ${path} has been changed`);});
      .on('unlink', path => { console.log(`File ${path} has been removed`); });
```

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since chokidar is based on the glob library it has a build in functionality that allows you to specify the working directory directly by setting the cwd option. So simply change your code to:

```
var fileLocation = path.join(__dirname, 'folder/');

var watcher = chokidar.watch(".", {
    persistent: true,
    cwd: fileLocation
});
```

and you will get just a file name in path.

Answer (score 0):

or you can try another way.

```
watcher.on('change', path => {

  const fileIndex = path.lastIndexOf('/') + 1;
  const fileFullName = path.substr(fileIndex);
  const filePureName = fileFullName.split('.')[0];
});
```