# Input file avoid duplicates

Tags: javascript

I have next HTML code for file upload, and I need JS that will check file names and display message if two same name and extension files are uploaded.

```
<div id="el_1">
<input name="file_1" id="file_1" type="file">
</div>
<div id="el_2">
<input name="file_2" id="file_2" type="file">
</div>
<div id="el_3">
<input name="file_3" id="file_3" type="file">
</div>
<input name="button" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" class="" style="">
```

Comment: You first need to get rid of your id duplicates.

Comment: And what is your question? You don't know how to access file properties? Or don't know how to do string comparison in JS? Or don't know JS and want us to write your code for you?

Comment: @kemicofa Thank you, I have changed code.

Comment: @rsm I do not know JS, I need someone to write it for me. I have spend last few hours on the met, and I could not find solution,

Comment: "I need JS code" - you know, you can hire someone to write code for you... StackOverflow is not a free coding service, we can only help you with specific problems when you are writing code yourself.

Comment: @Bergy I has hoping that someone will spend few minutes and write few JS lines for me. It is not all about money.

Comment: If you run into these kind of things it might be a good idea to invest a few hours into learning how to use jQuery ... these kind of things do not require a deep understanding of JS and it could save you a lot of time down the stretch.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to Muhamd Agoumi and T. Stoddard, I have prepared final solution for me, and I will like to share it with you.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en' class=''>
    <head><meta charset='UTF-8'>
        <meta name="robots" content="noindex">
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="file_1">
            <input name="file_1" id="file_1" class="files" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
        </div>
        <div class="file_2">
            <input name="file_2" id="file_2" class="files" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
        </div>
        <div class="file_3">
            <input name="file_3" id="file_3" class="files" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
        </div>
        <input name="button" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" class="" style="" onclick="checkDuplicates(event)">
        <script src='https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js'></script>
        <script >
            $('#file_1, #file_2, #file_3').change(function (e) {
                if ($('#file_1').val() != '' && $('#file_1').val() == $('#file_2').val() != '' && $('#file_2').val() || $('#file_1').val() != '' && $('#file_1').val() == $('#file_3').val() != '' && $('#file_3').val() || $('#file_2').val() != '' && $('#file_2').val() == $('#file_3').val() != '' && $('#file_3').val())
                {
                    alert("You can not send two or more same files.");
                }
            });
        </script>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            checkDuplicates = function(e){
              var arr = [];
              var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".files");
               fileInputs.forEach(function(input){
                if(arr.length == 0){
                  arr.push(input.files[0].name);
                } else {
                  if(arr.indexOf(input.files[0].name) > -1){
                    e.preventDefault();
                    alert("You can not send two or more same files.");
                  } else {
                    arr.push(input.files[0].name);
                  }
                }
              }); 
            };
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Shortly, there is two validations: First validation will be triggered instantly during file selection, when duplicated file is selected. This validation will be a warning for user that two same files are selected. In case that user ignores the first validation, second validation will be triggered at submit action. User will not be able to submit files as long as he does not remove duplicated file(s).

Thank you all for help!

Answer (score 3):

Here's a pure javascript solution that doesn't limit you to a set number of inputs.

You'll need to iterate through all of the input tags and see if any of them have the same file selected. You could use various methods to do this but regardless of how you do it you would want to look at the file name of the file that is selected. A file type input has a `files` attribute. It could contain more than one file but in your case it shouldn't. The `files` attribute is a `FileList`. Each element of the `FileList` has a name property that contains the file name including the extension. Here's a proof of concept:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
<form action="some action">
<div class="container">
   <input type="file" name="myFile1"  class="testFiles"><br>
   <input type="file" name="myFile2"  class="testFiles"><br>
   <input type="file" name="myFile3"  class="testFiles"><br>
   <input type="file" name="myFile4"  class="testFiles"><br>
   <input type="submit" name="Submit" onclick="checkDuplicates(event)">
</div>
</form>
<script type="text/javascript">
checkDuplicates = function(e){
  var arr = [];
  var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".testFiles");
   fileInputs.forEach(function(input){
    if(arr.length == 0){
      arr.push(input.files[0].name);
    } else {
      if(arr.indexOf(input.files[0].name) > -1){
        e.preventDefault();
        alert("there's a duplicate");
      } else {
        arr.push(input.files[0].name);
      }
    }
  }); 
};
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: That is it! Thank you very much!

Comment: You're welcome, but an up vote would be appreciated. I'm trying to build some reputation points.

Comment: I will like to, but I do not have enough reputations (Thanks for the feedback! Votes cast by those with less than 15 reputation are recorded, but do not change the publicly displayed post score.). Sorry.

Comment: I upvoted for you @T.Stoddard! One year late but it's never too late! :)

Answer (score 1):

you have to change the Id of the div so it must be unique like this way for example

```js
$('#file_1, #file_2, #file_3').change(function(e){
    if (($('#file_1').val() == $('#file_2').val()) || ($('#file_1').val() == $('#file_3').val()) || ($('#file_2').val() == $('#file_3').val()))
    {
      alert("one file or two are duplicated")
    }
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="file_1">
<input name="file_1" id="file_1" class="" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
</div>
<div class="file_2">
<input name="file_2" id="file_2" class="" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
</div>
<div class="file_3">
<input name="file_3" id="file_3" class="" title="" style="" multiple="0" type="file">
</div>
<input name="button" id="button" type="submit" value="Submit" class="" style="">
```

Comment: If I'm not mistaken, `$('#file').val()` takes the whole filepath so you need something like https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript in addition (if only the filename should be compared).

Comment: @mouhamd Agoumi Thank you very much. But I have received alert "one file or two are duplicated" as soon as I have uploaded first file. Can we prevent that behaviour?

Comment: you have to add a condition to see if it's not empty

Comment: `$('#file_1').val() != ''` will be enough to solve that problem

Answer (score 1):

@mouhamd Agoumi Thank you very much. I have changed code:

```
$('#file_1, #file_2, #file_3').change(function (e) {
            if ($('#file_1').val() != '' && $('#file_1').val() == $('#file_2').val() != '' && $('#file_2').val() || $('#file_1').val() != '' && $('#file_1').val() == $('#file_3').val() != '' && $('#file_3').val() || $('#file_2').val() != '' && $('#file_2').val() == $('#file_3').val() != '' && $('#file_3').val())
            {
                alert("one file or two are duplicated");
            }
        });
```