# Prevent Duplicate File Uploads via Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html-input

I'm trying to combine two concepts.  This code works...

HTML

```
  <input type="file" name="files" multiple>
     <ul id="file_list">
       <ul id="file_names">
       </ul>
      </ul>
```

Javascript

```
  const dt = new DataTransfer();

  $("#my_files").on('change', function(e){
   for(var i = 0; i < this.files.length; i++){
     let filearea = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3'}),
         fileName = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3', text: this.files.item(i).name});
     filearea.append('<ul class="button125">Delete</ul></ul></ul>')
       .append(fileName);
   $("#file_list > #file_names").append(filearea);
   };
   for (let file of this.files) {
   dt.items.add(file);
   }
   this.files = dt.files;
   });
```

Essentially I'm trying to create a list of attachments based on the user clicking to attach multiple files....This totally works and has been working well.

I'm trying to incorporate some logic so that if a user clicks on a duplicate file I can send an alert at the time of the user clicking on the duplicate file.

I've been using this solution to try to guide my solution...

[Input file avoid duplicates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54296646/input-file-avoid-duplicates)

But I can't quite make it out....I do have a solution that is close to working I think...

```
  const dt = new DataTransfer();

  $("#my_files").on('change', function(e){
   var arr = [];
   var fileInputs = document.querySelectorAll(".attachmentname3");
   fileInputs.forEach(function(input){
    if(arr.length == 0){
      arr.push(input.files[0].name);
      let filearea = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3'}),
          fileName = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3', text: input.files[0].name});
          filearea.append('<ul class="button125">Delete</ul></ul></ul>').append(fileName);
   $("#file_list > #file_names").append(filearea);
   for (let file of input.files) {
   dt.items.add(file);
   }
   input.files = dt.files;

   } else {
     if(arr.indexOf(input.files[0].name) > -1){
       e.preventDefault();
       alert("You can not send two or more same files.");
     } else {
       arr.push(input.files[0].name);
       let filearea = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3'}),
           fileName = $('<ul/>', {class: 'attachmentname3', text: input.files[0].name});
           filearea.append('<ul class="button125">Delete</ul></ul></ul>').append(fileName);
    $("#file_list > #file_names").append(filearea);
    for (let file of input.files) {
    dt.items.add(file);
    }
    input.files = dt.files;
     }
    };
  });
 });
```

I'm new to Javascript...or not very good at it....I realize in one case I'm referencing $this...and the other I'm using input.  I suspect that I'm confusing these two....

I'm currently getting an error on this line...

```
   arr.push(input.files[0].name);
```

I've been trying various approaches to solve this for the last 3 days and just can't quite figure out how to trigger the duplicate message once the user clicks on a duplicate.  Thanks in advance for any thoughts.

Comment: Your input element looks like this: `<input type="file" name="files" multiple>`. You can select multiple files. But how do you end in a situation where you have more files that are the same? You can only select a file once. In the question that you link to there are more input[type=file] elements -- in that situation the same file can be selected more than once.

Comment: It looks like they are trying to prevent uploads with the same file *name*.

Answer (score 0):

The error you are getting could be because of files[0] being undefined. Change to

```
  if(input.files?.[0]) arr.push(input.files[0].name);
```

Also, to be more precise, you may want to add file name as well as size to check for uniqueness.

Comment: @MayankKumarChadhari Thanks for taking the time to respond.  I appreciate it.  Unfortunately after making the change you suggested I'm still getting...TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading '0')