# Can I use "request" and "cheerio" libraries to extract data from a .html file?

Tags: node.js, web, request, cheerio

I'm creating a React Web Application and using request and cheerio to do some Web Scraping. I need to extract data from a .html file. The user enters with a .html in an input:

```
<input type='file' />
```

How can I extract data from the file? It is possible with those libraries?
I know that request needs an `url` and I guess that it will be the local path to file. I used the following code to do Web Scraping:

```
const foo = await new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    request.get(url, (err, res2, data) => {
        const $ = cheerio.load(data)
        let s = $("tbody < table.table_lt").text().replace(/\t/g, '').replace(/\n/g, '')
        resolve(s)
    })  
})
```

But this work just with Web.

Comment: You're using wrong tags on your question. This is not a question related to `node.js`. Try to understand how to ask: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask

Answer (score 0):

As answered here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31104553

> In Node.js, you can use [Path's parse module...](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_pathstring)

```
var path = require('path');
var file = '/home/user/dir/file.txt';

var filename = path.parse(file).base;
//=> 'file.txt'
```