# Javascript: Insert name of current file into a field?

Tags: javascript

I have several identical HTML files that all have different names:

```
3089.html
68985.html
101.html
...and more
```

Each file has an input field with an id of "productsku":

```
<input type='text' id='productsku' />
```

I would like this field to be filled with the name of the HTML file. I only want to use Javascript to do this (I don't want to use jQuery, as I don't want to load the jQuery library for such a small task).

Here is my Javascript code:

```
    <script>
        window.onload = function(){
    document.getElementById('productsku').value=location.pathname; 
}
    </script>
```

It works, but it puts the file name extension and path rather than just the name. 
e.g. it puts `/path/3089.html` rather than just "3089"

Is there any way I can correct this?

Here is a [JS fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/big_smile/930dy8wm/6/).

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get the file name from a full path using JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript)

Answer (score 4):

How about:

```js
const parts = location.pathname.split('/'); // split the pathname into parts
const [filename] = parts[parts.length - 1].split('.'); // take the filename from the last part of the path

document.getElementById('productsku').value = filename;
```

```html
<input type="text" id="productsku" />
```

Answer (score 1):

here is the possible Solution

```js
let path = 'domainNameOrIPAddress/path/3089.html';
// let path = location.pathname; // Use this to get actual result
let val = path.split('/').pop().replace('.html', '');
document.getElementById('productsku').value=val;
```

```html
<input type='text' id='productsku' />
```

Comment: Here is **a** solution

Comment: Not sure why you rolled-back the edit... it is **not THE** solution... it is one of many possible solutions

Comment: I did not said `Here is the only solution`, just said `Here is the solution` which indirectly meant the same that it is one of many possible solutions.

Comment: Sorry, but they mean exactly the same thing, and will be understood to mean exactly the same thing... I repeat, it is not the solution, and you should either edit it to say "a solution" or stop editing your answer when people correct it

Comment: @bhuvneshpattnaik check out this thread: https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/90117/what-is-the-difference-between-a-and-the. I hope you'll understand better what is the actual difference between *a* and *the*

Comment: Are we here to discuss the difference b/w a and the ?

Comment: Of course not, unless you roll-back edits to your post that are meant to improve its readability for other folks ;) Among others, the edits' purpose is to improve readability,  grammar, typos, etc. so if someone breaks this rule, it's ok to tell him not to do it ;) But you're right, we can close this discussion already.

Answer (score 0):

You could use RegEx to extract it...

```js
var path = "/this/that/other/12345.html";
console.log(path.match(/\/(\d+)\.html$/i)[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Hope this helps you:

```
const productsku = /\/([^/]+)\.html/.exec(location.pathname)[1]
document.getElementById('productsku').value=productsku;
```

Answer (score 0):

The better way is to extract the name from the path, like this :

```
<script>
    window.onload = function(){
        var locationName = location.pathname.substring(location.pathname.lastIndexOf('/')+1, location.pathname.lastIndexOf('.html'));
        document.getElementById('productsku').value=locationName; 
    }
</script>
```