# Add active class to an li when on URL

Tags: jquery

I am trying to add an active class to li based on the active URL,
This what I got, unfortunately, it is not working when the

```
<li class="scroll"><a href="index.php">Home</a></li>
```

and it will work when :

```
<li class="scroll"><a href="">Home</a></li>
```

The jQuery is:

```
jQuery(function($) {
     var path = window.location.href;
     if ( path == '' ) {
       path = 'index.php';
     }
     $('ul li a').each(function() {
      if (this.href === path) {
       $(this).parent().addClass('is-current');
      }
     });
    });
```

Thank you!

Comment: `console.log(path,path===this.href)`

Comment: `$(function() { var path = window.location.pathname; if ( path === '' )  path = 'index.php';  $('ul li a[href='+path+']').parent().addClass('is-current'); });`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason this is happening is that the URL will not be `mysite.com/index.php`

You need to have your active state based on the URL path.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Location

`window.location.pathname` is what you are looking for. That will return the end of the URL with a leading `/` and you can base your check on that string.

If you are on the base URL (usually the home page), the check won't contain a path and if you're on a sub page of the domain you can then check for instance:

```
// site.com/about
const path = window.location.pathname

if (path === '/about') {
  $('li').addClass('active')
}
```

Comment: Thank you!

      jQuery(function($) {
             var path = window.location.pathname;
             if ( path == '' ) {
               path = 'index.php';
             }
             $('ul li a').each(function() {
              if (this.pathname === path) {
               $(this).parent().addClass('is-current');
              }
             });
            });

Answer (score 0):

This is because `window.location.href` returns the full url, meaning something like

```
www.example.com/folder/index.php
```

Perhaps [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/423376/how-to-get-the-file-name-from-a-full-path-using-javascript) could help you, as you would only need the file name.

Comment: This isn't really an answer unless you can help the OP fix the issue. You're just describing the problem.

Comment: You are correct. Edited.